# How to create an installable package in a ppa the simple way

Tags: python, ppa

Because I can't figure out how to publish my program because I do not understand the packaging, I have some questions:

Why can't I just upload a directory of files* to the ppa, and a setup file that is executed if I type "sudo apt-get install package-name" and the setup-file only does these things:

1. Copy the files of the directory in the ppa to their location on the users's system
2. Install dependencies (pyhton3, python3-pyqt, and such)

Is this possible?

*The copied files include the main python script, data files and icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you really have some misconceptions about how packages are done in Debian/Ubuntu:

> Why can't I just upload a directory of files* to the ppa

Because that's dirty and the system shouldn't try to figure out what are you trying to do. Whenever you upload to a PPA you should upload the sources code in a tarball, that includes the `debian/` directory, and a signed `.dsc` file, and maybe a `.changes` file if you are not the original maintainer of the program.

I recommend you to read and reread the fine Debian Packaging Guide, and other resources online:

- http://www.webupd8.org/2010/01/how-to-create-deb-package-ubuntu-debian.html
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Packaging
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MOTU
- http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Debian-Binary-Package-Building-HOWTO/
- http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Debian-Binary-Package-Building-HOWTO/x169.html
- http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/336
- Google: Create DEB sources file

Comment: hm yes I know this and have already read some of this, but I hoped for a simple, not complex program it would be easier to upload

Comment: Welcome to Debian :D. No actually, once you have done it first time, whenever you do it again is more easier, is like *mount a bike*.

Comment: Thanks^^ I am already some steps further right now but still figuring something out. Perhaps you could take a look at this post right [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/347560/specify-the-install-place-in-a-package)?