# Specify the target directory in a package

Tags: python, ppa, packaging, dh-make

I created a package (with dpkk-build and dh_make) from my own program source and got a deb-binary. So far, so good. No if I'd upload the package to my ppa and installed it from there, the program would not work because I did not specify where it should install the files. After creating and configuring the debian folder (after dh_make), my project folder looks like:

```
/main.py (the programm)
/icons/...
/saves/...
/debian/...
```

Now my questions:

- How/where (perhaps in control or rules in /debian?) do I specify where to copy the first 3 files/folders to? I would like to copy my whole program including the main script to `/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/program-name`.
- Moreover I'd also need to copy a .desktop file to `/usr/share/applications` that executes the main.py script.

Where do I place the needed instructions?

EDIT

As the `dh_make` did not do itself but can be found in the docs [here](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html#install), I made an install-file in the /debian directory containing the files to be moved. After a `debuild -S` there was a subdirectory named like the package created, and in its tree structure (like the destination described in the install file) the files were placed. So I guess it will work on a regular install. Only one more question: How can I set `chmod+x` to those installed files?

Comment: Did you gave a look to this http://askubuntu.com/q/90764/169736?

Comment: Now I did. I saw an install file there about which I have already read. After my dh_make, there was no install file in the debian-directory. So if i create the file manually and specify all places in the 'file path' 'copy file to this path' -manner, installing would work (e.g. with apt-get install name)?

Comment: You should create files as you see fit that comply with the manual/usage of the guides, after you think everything is done you should run `lithian` to check that everything complies the directives (as double verification method).

Comment: So you mean that the install-file will be respected by dpkg-build? Don't want to mix things that aren't supposed to be used together

Comment: Did you ran `dch --create`?

Comment: Only now, but it threw an error because the changelog already existed due to dh_make.

Comment: That's the problem you shouldn't use `dh_make` but `dch`. Remove the old `debian/` directory and run on the clean sources `dch --create`

Comment: Ok, I tried it from the project folder. It throws an error because there is no debian directory.

But if I make an empty debian folder and run dch --create, there is only a changelog.dch file created, nothing else.

Comment: made an EDIT for the install-file

Comment: Ok you completely lost me, was the first issue fixed?

Comment: Hm yes, it seems like the install-file is working as intended. I did not install the package yet, but the files are listed in a subdirectory with the correct path. Still, they dont have execution permission (chmod+x) which they should have imo (at least after a regular install, right?), so I need to give them permissions.

Comment: I think you should have applied those permissions *before* packaging the deb file...

Comment: I have tried what you suggested, but still the  files are without permission. Oh wait. The python script has permissions, the .desktop file not.. strange

Comment: If you would like to ask that question separated. Also, how many questions I have answered? Could you please ask one for each solution I presented, I think this one is duplicated of the link I provided earlier.

Comment: Yes of course. Thank you a lot. Felt like "spamming" to many question would not be good, either. The question before answered by you was accepted ;) You could answer my question here with the install-file and I'll accept it

Comment: Err... if it's about the first question I think it should be closed of the link I provided earlier. The other issues merit their own questions.

Comment: Yes ok but the system cant accept a comment as an answer, the question has to be answered not commented

Comment: Just read your comments and try to structure a question around it, with the issue that were presented. Then delete the comment corresponding to the question. IE. The first issue was that you used `dh_make` instead `dch` the second: are permissions set for the python script. blah blah, and final question (each of them in their own post) why does the .desktop files don't have executable permissions. Something like that.

Comment: well i still use dh_make because dch did not solve anything.
Why don't you just answer this question with sth. like "create an install file in /debian", I remove my edit, accept your answer and then we'll take care of the other points?

Comment: [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/347711/how-to-add-permissions-to-files-installed-by-dpkg-buildpackage-or-debuild) is another question