# How to add permissions to files installed by dpkg-buildpackage or debuild

Tags: python, ppa, packaging

I build a package from my own source using dh_make and dpkg-buildpackage. The install-file in /debian specifies the destinations for the project files. To make the installed program work, they need to be executable / have execution permissions with chmod. In particular it is about a python script and a .desktop-file.

How do I set those permissions in setup? By only copying them to their destinations it is not done. It would be ok for me if I could trigger a command at the end of setup, or something like this, but don't know how to include this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .desktop file doesn't need execution permissions, your .py script does.

```
braiam@bt:~$ ls -l /usr/share/app-install/desktop/deluge.desktop 
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1276 Aug  6  2012 /usr/share/app-install/desktop/deluge.desktop
braiam@bt:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/deluge
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 289 Jan 27  2013 /usr/bin/deluge
```

You should before packaging have set the executable bit on the python script, that dpkg will take care of the rest.

The .desktop file is a configuration file read by xdg, and has it own variables set to execute the needed binary:

```
cat /usr/share/app-install/desktop/deluge.desktop
[...]
GenericName=BitTorrent Client
X-GNOME-FullName=Deluge BitTorrent Client
Comment=Download and share files over BitTorrent
Exec=deluge-gtk %U
Icon=deluge
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Network;FileTransfer;P2P;GTK
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=application/x-bittorrent;x-scheme-handler/magnet;
```

As you wan see it has a `Exec` variable that takes care of the execution when the file is accessed.

Comment: .desktop files without x permission will be warned to be "untrusted".

Comment: mmm... interestion, then what is the method to include this files?

Comment: My DEB package copies executable .desktop files as executable on installation - I believe permissions should all be set correctly in the source to avoid issues but I dont know how setup.py handles this.

Comment: That was the same thing I commented before to another question of the [same user](http://askubuntu.com/questions/347560/specify-the-install-place-in-a-package#comment445592_347560)

Comment: LOL - then it must be the truth :)

Answer (score 7):

You could create a post installation script:

```
gedit debian/packagename.postinst
```

This is just a normal script, so the following instructions will do:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
chmod 755 /path/to/pythonscript.py
exit 0
```

Alternatively, you could exclude the file from having its permissions altered by `dh_fixperms`. This can be done within `debian/rules`:

```
%:
    dh  $@ --with python2

override_dh_fixperms:
    dh_fixperms --exclude path/to/pythonscript.py
```

The first option is preferable because `dh_fixperms` does other useful things like changing the owner of a file, and excluding the file prevents `dh_fixperms` from doing anything useful. Also note that in the first option, there is a preceding slash **/**path/to/pythonscript.py as it is an absolute path, whereas the second option is relative to the debian subdirectory.

EDIT: @AlexisWilke has mentioned a better alternative for option 2, that is:

```
%:
    dh  $@ --with python2

override_dh_fixperms:
    dh_fixperms
    chmod 755 path/to/pythonscript.py
```

This allows `dh_fixperms` to work its magic followed by the minor necessary fix.

Comment: Couldn't we do `dh_fixperms` first, the a `chmod a+x path/to/pythonscript.py`? — because that way dh_fixperms does everything right as per debian and then you fix a few more things your way. Correct?

Comment: Yes, I think you are right, modified answer to suit.